# What is the idea of watgtail root[depth=0] page?

Tags: wagtail

Please i need to understand the idea of wagtail root[depth=0] page. Because for me homepages must be on the root level but currently all homepages are on depth=1 level, why and what is the idea to have root level page.
I checked docs etc, but didnt find clear info of this idea.

Also why homepages[depth=1] related to site object and not root[depth=0]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mostly an implementation detail to make Wagtail's internal logic simpler. For example, the `Page` model has `copy` and `move` methods, which take the new parent page as a parameter. Having a fixed, non-editable page at the root level means that there's always a meaningful value we can pass as the parent - if the root node wasn't there, we'd have to implement separate code paths for "move a page to a new parent" versus "move a page to the top level".

However, there's also one place where the root page is directly meaningful to the site admin: it's possible to assign permissions to that page (through the Settings -> Groups area). Since permissions propagate down the page tree, this means that the permission will apply to all pages across all sites. For example, if you want to give a (non-superuser) group the ability to create new homepages, you can do that by giving them 'add' permission on the root page.

Comment: Thanks now its more clear. Left one thing to undestand: is it some scenario or needs in wagtail when we have to use two root level pages?

Comment: No, there is only ever one page at the root level (depth=0), which cannot be moved or edited. There can be multiple pages at the next level (depth=1) - this is often used to host multiple sites on the same Wagtail instance.